# Change Workflow State to Approved

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, content-approval

I've build my own approval workflow. 
My workflow is finished, but the state of the workflow (state in library) is "finished".
When I finish the standard SharePoint approval workflow the state is "approved".

How can I set the state of the workflow to "approved"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By using the SharePoint object model, you can add your own workflow
>   status that appears in the workflow association column. Each workflow
>   status value corresponds to an integer that represents its place in a
>   zero-based ordered list of column values. The first 15 values in the
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowStatus enumeration are
>   reserved by Windows SharePoint Services for internal use.
>
> To add a custom status value, define a new StatusColumn element under
>   ExtendedStatusColumnValues in Workflow.xml. The first status column
>   value you specify is assigned the integer value of 15; the second
>   status value, 16; and so on.

You can see more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc514224%28office.12%29.aspx#MOSS2007DevWorkflowSolutions_SettingOutcomeValues).

if you would like to extend the workflow statuses enumeration you can try to use [this approach](http://debapk.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-change-sharepoint-workflow.html).